# mysql client won't run on my Ubuntu instance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

Running a LAMP server on Ubuntu 12.04.  Trying to run mysql from the command line like so:

```
root@server:~# mysql -u 'wp-user' -p
```

and I'm getting

```
mysql: ambiguous option '--v' (vertical, version)
```

The mysql service is running fine, and is serving my wp site.  Why can't I login as well from the command line, and what is up with this error regarding options when I haven't set any regarding --v?

I'm fairly certain that I have successfully logged in to mysql from command-line before.  Rebooting does not solve it.  I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

Comment: Do you have an `alias` set?

Comment: Any aliases set ?

Comment: not intentionally... I am novice with Ubuntu.  I tried prepending with a "\" as below, no change.

Comment: bump...  should I just try reinstalling mysql in the hopes that it magically fixes itself?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an alias set. Prefix mysql with \ to short circuit any alias

```
\mysql -u 'wp-user' -p
```

Comment: no change when I prepend the backslash